# Magento 2 Can't add Attribute option upto 100 ? Is there any limit for the option?

Tags: magento2, eav, option, eav-attributes

I have an issue with the product options. There are 500 option for the attribute but can't add after 100 options.

Can you please let me know about this issue?

The Product Attribute is successfully saved but the option value not showing.

Comment: You cannot save or cannot add more?

Comment: What is the type of your attribute?

Comment: add option button working but after save attribute that option not showing

Comment: both multi select and select

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely your PHP max input vars setting is to low, and it happens to cap at out 100 entries. Verify what this is set to, and raise it to something like 100,000 . Magento backend forms can contain many inputs. If you want to get a rough estimate of this value on your current attribute, try going to the admin page for it, opening up the web console, running jQuery("input").length and see the value.

Comment: now it's working fine I have added limit in .htaccess file php_value max_input_vars 10000.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Comment: In which file i need to change this 'php_value max_input_vars'  value

Comment: I tried it in version 2.1.5 but doesnt work. If I add php.ini in root folder and add input var, it display in phpinfo but site break-down. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could comment rather than answer, but FWIW I have a system with well in excess of 100 options for a question, however, the more you have the more cpu/memory the back office uses up. It might be it runs out of memory or times out. Suggest you make sure the php settings file has a goodly chunk of memory e.g. in GB rather than MB. Also there are magento recommendations for php timeout wait time, again make sure this is not the standard 30 seconds. It may also be a value that has control characters in it so for a test only use alpha characters, finally it is worth checking the web server logs (apache nginx) and syslog. HTH

Answer (score -1):

```
php_value max_input_vars 10000
```